# readr with gzip files in R?

Tags: r, readr

Does read_table work on .gz files like read.table?

My attempt to use read_table(gzipped(filename)) did not work. Wondering if there is an alternative. I do not want to unzip the file on hdd, but could do it in ram (though not sure how) if that helps.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation. `library(readr); help(read_csv)`. See the comments on the "file" argument: "Files ending in .gz, .bz2, .xz, or .zip will be automatically uncompressed."

Comment: @Imo if folks read documentation SO would not exist.

Comment: It should work, yes.

Comment: didnt quite work for me. i ended up using scan which was significantly faster than read.table.  i had to modify my logic to deal with a long vector instead of a matrix